# Backbone multiple event bindings

Tags: backbone.js

I have a div with id `#content` in which I render a view (`view.el: "#content"`) with a model.
In this view I have an event (`"click #save": "save"`).

When I override the view (= I render the same view on a new model, for example) the `save` event fires twice.

This happens because the [`this.undelegateEvents();`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L942) method unbinds events using the cid and every new view has a different cid.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you instantiate a new view, you will need to call `undelegateEvents` on the old view.